# Windows 8.1 installation on non-UEFI machine fails with error 0x80070570

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, installation, bios

I am trying to install Windows 8.1 on a clean (formatted) partition on an older non-UEFI-PC (BIOS is from 2008), but it keeps giving me the error:

`Windows cannot install required files. The file may be corrupt or missing. Make sure all files required for installation are available and restart the installation. Error code: 0x80070570`

I used Rufus with the option MBR/BIOS (UEFI-CSM) to make a bootable USB stick with an official ISO file from Microsoft (I calculated the SHA1 hash of the ISO and it should be fine - see https://www.heidoc.net/php/myvsdump_details.php?id=P1503F62201Ax64Lde).

After the installation failed, I checked the `setupact` file which said `Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-wmi-core-providerhost_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.17415_none_0bc263c493833ebe\WmiPrvSE.exe` was corrupted, so I figured out `sources\install.wim` on my USB stick might be corrupted and I compared its SHA1 hash with another `install.wim` file I had received by extracting the ISO file (using WinRAR) - the hashes were indeed different.

I then replaced `install.wim` on my USB stick with the other `install.wim` file (the hashes are now the same) and tried again - without success. I still get the same error, `setupact` now says: `Calling WIMApplyImage (flags = 0x180)... [...] file corrupted [...] E:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-i..-wow64-setupdll001f_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16384_none_dd2bbcb0858e0596\_setup.dll (Error = 1392)`

The PC now runs Windows 7 Enterprise, which was previously installed using the same method (Rufus, official ISO, MBR, etc.). Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why aren't you using Windows to create the boot? Are you sure there are no disk errors? If the disk supports SMART then report on it, otherwise check the Event Log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Burning the image onto a CD (can be done with Rufus, too) instead of using a USB stick solved the problem in the end.